# How to hide set method of an implemented property from an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, encapsulation

Greetings everyone...

If I have the following interface:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    int property { get; set; }
}
```

And the following implementation:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
// anything
}
```

How can I hide the `set` method of property from the instances of `MyClass`... In other words, I don't want the `set` method of `property` to be public, is that possible?

It would be easy to do with abstract class:

```
abstract class IMyInterface
{
    int property { get; protected set; }
}
```

Then I could only `set` the `property` within the class that implements the abstract class above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the following interface the set method will be unavailable when classes are manipulated via the interface:

```
interface IMyInterface
{ 
   int property { get; }
}
```

You could then implement the class like this:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
  int property { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that hide the "property" from the interface?

Comment: It will remove the setter from the interface, you can still read the property.

Comment: The setter in the implemented class will not be visible as it is nit entered in th interface. The setter **will** be available within the implemented class.

Answer (score 7):

Don't have the `set` in the interface to begin with. You can still implement it as `private`.

You can't "hide" it, it's part of the contract. If you don't want it to be part of the contract, don't define it.

Comment: @Girardi - What don't you get? If you define it in an interface, it _has_ to be implemented. If you don't want to implement it, don't define it in an interface.

Comment: I want the set method to be implemented, but I want it to be visible only inside the class that implements the interface, while the property should be visible even outside that class...

Comment: What is visible *inside of the class* is a question of *implementation* and therefore should not be declared in interface. It's up to concrete classes. Interface only specifies public contract.

Answer (score 2):

If some implementations will only implement some parts of an interface, it may be a good idea to subdivide the interface into the parts which each implementation will either implement completely or not at all, and then define interfaces which inherit all the common combinations of them.  Adapting your example:

```
interface IMyReadableInterface
{
    int property { get; }
}
interface IMyFullInterface : IMyReadableInterface
{
    new int property { get; set; }
}
```

Classes which want to support read-write access should implement IMyFullInterface; those which want to only support read access should only implement IMyReadableInterface.  This segregation will not require any extra work for implementations of either interface which are written in C# and implement `property` implicitly.  Code which implements `property` in VB, or explicitly implements `property` in C#, will have to define two implementations of `property`--a read-only one and a read-write one, but such is life.  Note that while one could define an `IMyWritableInterface` which just had a setter, and have `IMyFullInterface` inherit both `IMyReadableInterface` and `IMyWritableInterface`, `IMyFullInterface` would still have to define a read-write property of its own, and when using explicit implementation one would then have to define *three* properties (I really don't understand why C# can't use a read-only and write-only property together as thought they were a read-write property, but it can't).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the setter to be part of the interface but for some reason it does not make sense for it to be used on a particular implementer (in this case MyClass) you can always throw an exception in the setter (such as an InvalidOperationException). This will not protect you at compile time, only at run time. It is a bit strange though, as code that operates on the interface has no idea whether calling the setter is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly cases where you want the interface to have a `set` and then hide it in some concrete class.

I believe the code below shows what we want to accomplish. I.e. the implementation hides the setter, but any `IMyInterface` aware component will have access to it.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Property = 123;                 // Error
    ((IMyInterface)myClass).Property = 123; // OK
}
```

It's basically the same pattern you often see for `IDisposable.Dispose()` where you have an [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). Here's an example for completeness.

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int Property { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface, IDisposable
{
    public int Property { get; private set; }

    int IMyInterface.Property
    {
        get => Property;
        set => Property = value;
    }
    
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {}
}
```

### Too much typing :(

`C#` doesn't help us much here. Ideally, it would be possible to have an explicit interface implementation for the setter:

```cs
// In C# 10 maybe we can do this instead:
public class MyFutureClass : IMyInterface
{
    public int Property { get; IMyInterface.set; }
}
```

See `C#` feature proposal [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4190).

Answer (score 0):

There is no protected or private in interface, everything is public. Either you don't define any set or use it as public.